# OpenLayers: Unable to close popup when added using call from outside map

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers

I have written a basic function to allow me to display a popup from a link outside the map. The functionality to open the popup is working fine, but I can't then close it.

Demo link: http://www.catchingtherain.com/bikestats/stations.php - click on links in left-hand tabbed panels.

Here's a bit more detail ...

A typical map has about 300 features on a vector layer 'stations' loaded from kml. These are activated onload using

```
select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(stations);           
stations.events.on({
                "featureselected": onFeatureSelect,
                "featureunselected": onFeatureUnselect
                });
map.addLayer(stations);
map.addControl(select);
select.activate();
```

which works fine - I can open and close popups.

With my off-map links I am calling onclick="showMyPopup([x]) with [x] being an ID attribute loaded in from the kml. The showMyPopup function is

```
function showMyPopup(myID){
    for(var a = 0; a < stations.features.length; a++){    //loop through all the features
    var feature = stations.features[a];
    if (feature.attributes.ID.value == myID) {            //until it finds the one with the matching ID attribute
       var content = "<h4>" + feature.attributes.name + "</h4>" + feature.attributes.description;
       popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
                                     feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                                     new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
                                     content,
                                     null, true, onPopupClose);
       feature.popup = popup;
       map.addPopup(popup);
       }
    }
}
```

This opens the correct popup from the stations layer as expected, and I can see the popup using the DOM inspector on the stations layer just as it would appear if loaded by clicking on the map feature, but there's then seemingly no way of closing it. The original features on the stations layer are working fine though (opening and closing).

Any help would be much appreciated (maybe there's a simpler way of tackling this?)

Thanks, James

PS and just in case, here's the onFeatureUnselect function ...

```
function onFeatureUnselect(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        if(feature.popup) {
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            delete feature.popup;
        }
     }
```

Comment: cool sample and you perfect describe your problem - up voted :-D

Comment: Thanks - first question I've ever posted here so it's nice to know I'm doing it right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your on `onPopupClose()` function is:

```
function onPopupClose(evt) {
    select.unselectAll();
}
```

When you select feature from map and click on popup's Close icon, then feature will be unselected, but popup is not closed yet. Then, `onFeatureUnselect` event is triggered, and popup is actually closed.

When you create popup by `showMyPopup()` function, you are not selecting it. `onPopupClose()` is called, but it doesn't close popup. `onFeatureUnselect` is not triggered.

I suggest to select feature in `showMyPopup()` function. `featureselected` event will be fired and popup is created by `onFeatureSelect()`, and user can close popup both with popup's Close icon and unselecting feature on map.

But alas, there's a possible bug (or unexpected behaviour) in OL, when you select feature with code and try to unselect it with clickout. It's described here: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2012-September/026349.html One possible fix is to set SelectControl.handlers.feature.lastFeature manually.

```
function showMyPopup(myID){
    for(var a = 0; a < stations.features.length; a++){    //loop through all the features
        var feature = stations.features[a];
        if (feature.attributes.ID.value == myID) {            //until it finds the one with the matching ID attribute

            // select is your SelectFeature control
            select.select(feature);
            // Fix for unselect bug
            select.handlers.feature.lastFeature = feature;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it - perfect. I knew there was something wrong with repeating the whole popup content etc but just couldn't get my head around it!

There's one tiny 'bug' in that I need to add something to close any existing popups when a new one is opened, but I can actually use it to my advantage because in some cases I have a start point and end point so it would be good to have them both displayed at once.

Comment: [Edit: durr, click on the tick!] OK, first question I've ever posted - how do I now mark this as the answer?

Comment: "I need to add something to close any existing popups when a new one is opened" - if you select.unselectAll(), all selected features will be unselected and onFeatureUnselect() is triggered, which closes popups. so I guess you don't have to worry about closing previous popups.

Comment: Thanks. On reflection I've implemented that as I think it makes a better user experience. If I want to display a start and end point I'll write another function to handle that I think.

Answer (score 0):

I take a look in the OpenLayers sources and there is in Popup.js something like that ...

```
    ...
    var closePopup = callback || function(e) {
        this.hide();
        OpenLayers.Event.stop(e);
    };
    OpenLayers.Event.observe(this.closeDiv, "touchend", 
            OpenLayers.Function.bindAsEventListener(closePopup, this));
    OpenLayers.Event.observe(this.closeDiv, "click", 
            OpenLayers.Function.bindAsEventListener(closePopup, this));
    ...
```

It seems to me if you add your own closePopup function you need to call the hide function in your code.